# Do I need to modify my smartwatch firmware to modify its OS?

Tags: operating-system, firmware, sony-smartwatch

I recently bought a smartwatch on AliExpress and wanted to know as tech-passionate if I could modify its OS. Throughout my research on the web, I have learnt about firmware in cpu and OS. As stated in my title, I wonder if I need to overwrite the firmware to overwrite the OS, or can I just overwrite the OS? Whether one or the other, I also wonder about how I should proceed.

I have done some research on the internet on that matter, but none seems to answer my question and I need more guidance.

Comment: Yeah, ok, you cannot perform this task, it is beyond you ATM.  Keep on studying, learning and amassing experience.